# How to call things you find at the sidewalk which are still useful?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

Is there a phrase for things people **put out on the street** which they do not need anymore? I am referring to **free, still functional stuff** such as books, shoes, a lamp, a cupboard, ... you name it.
I find it quite hard to use one word for all these different items.

#### Example sentence

> On my home I saw so many ____ people put on the sidewalk such as a candle holder, a pair of ladies' shoes and bathtub for children.

Comment: 'Surplus to requirements', but most signs I've seen say 'Please help yourself'.

Comment: Reusable garbage, scavenged objects?

Comment: Found objects (if artful) or treasures of the curb (made that up).

Comment: You'll probably get close votes unless you propose an example sentence. Something like "I couldn't believe someone left a perfectly good Picasso out as a _____" would do--closer to actual use will get the best answers.

Comment: *cast-offs*....

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people might call these **hidden treasures**, meaning that, with a little rummaging through the discard pile, something useful or valuable might be found. This is often how that Picasso might be discovered (at a yard sale, for example, but sometimes in the trash as well), but it applies just as well to the smaller things that someone might find to be still useful to them. (They say "one man's trash is another man's treasure.")

If someone knowingly discards a useful item by the curb, they may post a sign that says "**Free for the taking**." This lets passersby know that there might be something of value and they are welcome to take it.